# SQL*Loader: Multiple row delimeter

Tags: sql-loader

I have a flat file that needs to be load into a table via SQL*Loader.

The content of the flat file is like:

> AAA|BBB
>
> CCC|DDD
>
> EEE|FFF

Below is my expected result after loaded into the table:

> AAA
>
> BBB
>
> CCC
>
> DDD
>
> EEE
>
> FFF

So far, I am just able to put "|" as the row delimiter and the control file is like:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'TEST.dat' "STR '|'" 
TRUNCATE  
INTO TABLE TBL_TEST
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(TEXT)
```

The output for above are:

> AAA
>
> BBB
>
> DDD
>
> FFF

Where `CCC` and `EEE` are missing due to the new line.

Is there a way to specify multiple row delimiters?
In my case, the row delimiters are "|" and "\n".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could, it would be real complicated.  First make the data source give you the data in the right format.  Failing that, preprocess the file with a script to replace the pipe characters with a carriage return. Or, load as-is into a staging table, then manipulate from there with standard SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try to manipulate the flat file before load.